# How to clear data ina DataTable in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

How can I clear the contents of a dataTable??

The user will import a textfile and then the data from that textfile will be displayed in a dataTable. When the user navigate to other pages and then decided to make an import again, the data from the previous import is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Put the bean in the request or view scope instead of the session scope.