# dataTable show copy of records

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I am working on JSF with primefaces,where i am using [dataTable row Editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf) which contains the data from database,

**Problem**

- After editing the  rows , i used to remove the rows from table , but the dataTable is showing the copy of the remaining records,

**Eg:**
[image]

**JSF Page:**

```
<p:dataTable var="perreq" value="#{leaverequest.perRequestList}" id="perrequestlist" editable="true"  >
        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update=":form0:form2:acivitydatatable,perrequestlist,:form0:form:growl" listener="#{leaverequest.onEdit}" />  
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"  listener="#{leaverequest.onCancel}" />  

            <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:100px;"><h:outputText value="#{perreq.ename}" /></p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="From" style="width:60px;"><h:outputText value="#{perreq.perFrom}" /></p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="To" style="width:60px;"><h:outputText value="#{perreq.perTo}"/></p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Date" style="width:80px;">  
            <h:outputText  value="#{perreq.dateOfPermission}" >
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Reason" style="width:200px;"><h:outputText value="#{perreq.reason}" /></p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Tl Comments" style="width:200px;"><h:outputText value="#{perreq.tlComments}" /></p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Comments" style="width:160px;">  
            <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
            <h:outputText value="" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <h:inputText value="#{leaverequest.perComments}"  style="width:150px;" label="Year" maxlength="100"/>  
            </f:facet>  
            </p:cellEditor>  
            </p:column>  
                <p:column headerText="Status" style="width:70px;">  
                <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:outputText value="#{perreq.status}" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{leaverequest.statusResult}" style="width:100px;" >  
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Accept" itemValue="Accepted"/>
                 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reject" itemValue="Rejected"/>  
                 </h:selectOneMenu>  
            </f:facet>  
            </p:cellEditor>  
            </p:column >  
            <p:column width="80px;"><p:rowEditor/></p:column>  
 </p:dataTable>
```

**Bean with getter n setter :**

```
 public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event)
 {  
    getPendingPermssionRequestDB();        
 } 
  public List<PendingRequestBean> getPerRequestList() 
  {
    return perRequestList;
  }
    public void setPerRequestList(List<PendingRequestBean> perRequestList) 
    {
        this.perRequestList = perRequestList;
    }

  public void getPendingPermssionRequestDB()
  {
        try
        {

   //Modify list and retrieve from DB
            Session hibernateSession=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Query query=hibernateSession.createQuery("select a from Permissionrecord as a");
            List<PendingRequestBean> l=(List<PendingRequestBean>)query.list();
            this.perRequestList=l;
            hibernateSession.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: Actually it's much more helpful to provide some code either than a picture showing what's happening.

Comment: I have added JSF code with respective bean class,

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the row's checkmark after editing it, an event is generated (I think you already are using this). Just invoke a listener method there where you remove the current row from the table and update the entire table:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" update="table" />
```

And that's your managed bean's event, supossing `tableElements` is the list which holds your `dataTable` values:

```
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {  
    tableElements.remove((Element) event.getObject());
}
```

**See also:**

- [Primefaces dataTable row editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion , it actually it doesn't work, after editing the row , the list hold the correct value, but in **JSF page only it shows copy of records**

Comment: What do you mean by `a copy of records`? Is your query at `getPendingPermssionRequestDB` loading the correct values?

Comment: Yes and copy of records Means  it shows old data , see **third table** in the image i have attached

Comment: My problem is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844183/how-to-clear-data-ina-datatable-in-jsf

Comment: You're actually only performing a `list` operation when you edit your row. How do you pretend to have your results changed? You actually are not modifying the DB (and consequently neither `perRequestList`) so table rows will keep the same as at the beginning.

Comment: See  i am just added the method where the jsf page linked , i will do all modification inside the `getPendingPermssionRequestDB()` ,i didnt display it, but i wil do it in  `getPendingPermssionRequestDB()`